# Getting PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeCode() on Admin

Tags: configurable-product, product-attribute, admin-panel, administration

Suddenly I am getting a fatal error, when I go the Manage products page on Magento Admin, Can anyone suggest what could be the reason ?

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getAttributeCode() on a
>   non-object in
>   /app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php on line
>   1186,

Comment: Did you import your products in some way. I seen similar strange errors like this when I did an import, and had an attribute set on the attribute set but not the product, or the other way around.

Comment: is it possible to find out what might be the issue ? by enabling the log

Comment: You will need to walk through the code in xdebug or use log statements to establish which attribute(s) are causing the problem.

Comment: Do you know which version of Magento your running?

Comment: Try to compile. Usually works.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when you uninstall modules adding custom attributes to your products.

If you recently uninstalled some extension without a clear uninstall this may be the cause.

Try also manually clearing your Magento cache. Use the two red buttons to clear cache, do not simply `refresh`.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Following from Phoenix128 answer a couple of time this issue happened was able to resolve it by removing the orphaned custom attribute/s from the Attribute set.

Go into Catalog > Attributes > Manage Attribute sets open up the attribute set that the product in question belongs to (most likely 'Default') and look for attributes that may have been added by the extension that was recently uninstalled.

Drag across to the right to remove from the attribute set, hit save.